# Angular Highcharts error missing module for candlestick type

Tags: highcharts, angular-highcharts

When trying to do a Highcharts candle stock chart with Angular Highcharts:
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular

I get an error seen here:

```
 ERROR Error: Highcharts error #17: www.highcharts.com/errors/17/?missingModuleFor=candlestick
 - missingModuleFor: candlestick
    at Object.<anonymous> (highcharts.js:12:238)
```

The link says "The requested series type does not exist"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix was to change:

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
```

to

```
import * as Highcharts from "highcharts/highstock";
```

Also for indicators don't forget :

```
import IndicatorsAll from "highcharts/indicators/indicators-all";
IndicatorsAll(Highcharts);
```

Importing modules in mentioned on the highcharts-angular wiki:
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#to-load-a-module

Also pass in the constructorType argument as mentioned here:
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#options-details

```
<highcharts-chart
  [Highcharts]="Highcharts"
  [constructorType]="'stockChart'"
  [options]="chartOptions"
></highcharts-chart>
```

There are also demos listed here:
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#online-examples